# Firebase Image Upload - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload Image to firebase storage but I am neither seeing the progress dialog nor the toast message.

The debug breakpoint is not even stopping at those lines.

Please help.

```
  ib_profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_modifyImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivity(intent_modifyImage);
        }
    });
}

//Image Capture Activity Result
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
        progressDialog.show();
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        StorageReference filepath = storageReference_image.child("profile_photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this,"Upload Complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: check my ans and ask me if you have]any query

Comment: if your progress dialog doesn't show, it seems like your `onActivityResult` doesn't even get called. Did you run the code under a debugger to verify if you get into `onActivityResult`?

Comment: yes. I called a wrong method after getting the intent @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: So the problem is solved then?

Comment: @NileshRathod hi. The debug is giving a null filepath in the try-cathc block. Let me know if I need to give any specific permissions in the manifest.xml

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen not yet.

Comment: you need to add read external storage permission in manifiest file

Comment: @SeshagiriRaoKornepati check my updated ans

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button chooseImg, uploadImg;
ImageView imgView;
int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 111;
Uri filePath;
ProgressDialog pd;

//creating reference to firebase storage
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://fir-example-c4312.appspot.com");    //change the url according to your firebase app


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    chooseImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chooseImg);
    uploadImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadImg);
    imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("Uploading....");


    chooseImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    uploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(filePath != null) {
                pd.show();

                StorageReference childRef = storageRef.child("image.jpg");

                //uploading the image
                UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.putFile(filePath);

                uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Failed -> " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();

        try {
            //getting image from gallery
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);

            //Setting image to ImageView
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**don't forget to Change Rules in firebase console**

By default we are not allowed to access firebase storage without authentication. To change it go to firebase console using any web browser. Open the firebase project that you have used in above steps and go to Storage and then Rules tab. Now change read and write rules to true as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: from what I see in the question, OP is already using Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 0):

try this method,its worked for me

Inside onActivityResult,

```
      StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(---STORAGE_BUCKET---);
                    StorageReference imagePathReference = storageRef.child("image");
                    final Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    try {
                        bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

      // convert bitmap to byte array to save image in firebase storage
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    if (bmp != null) {
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bos);
                    }
                    byte[] dataNew = bos.toByteArray();


  uploadTask = imagePathReference.putBytes(dataNew);
                    try {
                        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                             // success  
                            }

                        });
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }
```